# How to update the injected calls' address after patching binary?

Tags: ida, pe, patching

After using IDA analysing a dll file, I replaced a call with another one. That is, replacing `CALL xxxx` with `CALL ds:yyyy`. (`ds:yyyy` has been referenced by other locations already). And I used IDA to patch the binary.

But the problem is, when executing the module, `ds:yyyy` is not updated based on the module imagebase, and therefore an invalid address.

How can I deal with this kind of situation? Need I patch the reloc section too?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the address yyyy ? Is it an address from another module, an address that changes everytime you launch the binary, or a static address ?

Comment: @Spl3en Thanks for reply. I have managed to solve this. It is an address that would be changed every time I launch it because of the ASLR and address relocation. I add a reloc record in relocation table and it runs well.

Answer (score 1):

Answer it myself. It is actually a portable executable. And the addresses that are hard-coded will be updated every time I launch it by relocation table.

I modified the table by tools and it runs well.